# Phrase for something that isn't as good as it once was

Tags: phrases

Specifically a relationship which fell apart as time wore on.

Comment: The [honeymoon was over](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/The+honeymoon+is+over) and she had the [seven-year itch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_seven-year_itch). As it turned out, her personal trainer Paco was there for her.

Answer (score 3):

A common expression is *to lose the [spark](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Spark)  in a relashionship:* ( from TFD)

> - vivacity, enthusiasm, or humour

- 5 Reasons Your Relationship Has  [Lost Its Spark](http://www.mindbodygreen.com/0-12164/5-reasons-your-relationship-has-lost-its-spark-how-to-get-it-back.html).
- Why the [Spark](http://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/compassion-matters/201203/why-the-spark-fades-in-relationship) Fades in a Relationship.

> - Countless couples complain of losing the “spark” in their relationship. Some chalk it up to evolved differences, a slow growing apart, or sheer familiarity. The wave of “deadness” that can submerge a relationship after the first thrilling months or years have caused many couples to lose hope, and even look elsewhere for the excitement of newfound intimacy.

Answer (score 2):

You could say that the relationship has *grown stale*. [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/stale):

> **4.** having lost freshness, vigor, quick intelligence, initiative, or the like, as from overstrain, boredom, or surfeit:
>   *He had grown stale on the job and needed a long vacation.*

Answer (score 2):

"Lost its lustre" is a nice way of putting it.

> Lustre - 
>   1A gentle sheen or soft glow.
>   1.2 Glory or distinction.

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/lustre

"We grew apart" is a more relationship-specific phrase.

Comment: 'Lost its shine' is another variant.

Comment: @ErikKowal I was actually thinking of including that as an alternative, but I feared it would sound a little redundant. "Lustre" has a nicer sound to it, at any rate.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to include a connotation of inevitability, you could say the relationship had **run its course** (though that also implies it is over, or nearly so).

Answer (score 0):

Once you get past a certain age you can always crack the time-honoured joke: ***That relationship is like me, it's seen better days***

Answer (score 0):

"Getting to be a job" or "Turning into a job" refers to a relationship that is becoming too similar to the daily grind of one's employment.

Answer (score 0):

The relationship became **humdrum** Oxford Dictionaries define it as

[Lacking excitement or variety; boringly monotonous:](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/humdrum)

> You hear your friends tell stories about how **humdrum** their marriage is so you think that maybe that's just how marriage is after all.

Answer (score 0):

**Deterioration**  is widely used to describe relationships that fall apart as time wears on. (**Disintegration** is also used, but not as widely.) [[Ngram]](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=disintegrating%20relationship%2C%20deteriorating%20relationship&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdisintegrating%20relationship%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdeteriorating%20relationship%3B%2Cc0)

*Deterioration*, noun:

1. the act or process of deteriorating.
2. the state or condition of having deteriorated.
3. a gradual decline, as in quality, serviceability, or vigor.

Examples:

> [This Brutal Anecdote Reveals The Deteriorating Relationship Between Obama And Democrats](http://www.businessinsider.com/obama-harry-reid-anecdote-reveals-tension-2014-8#ixzz3McGjqs00)
>
> [How Ronaldo & Mourinho's relationship deteriorated at Real Madrid](http://www.goal.com/en-gb/news/3277/la-liga/2013/08/07/4170812/how-ronaldo-mourinhos-relationship-deteriorated-at-real)

Answer (score 0):

The verb *sour* can describe the deterioration of a relationship. Example from a Cambridge dictionary:

> This affair has soured relations between the two countries.

Answer (score -1):

- "a relationship that became **tasteless**."
- "a relationship grown **insipid**."

> tasteless - "arousing no interest, dull. [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tasteless)
>
> insipid - "Lacking qualities that excite, stimulate, or interest" [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/insipid)